# Drupal 8 - Leaflet module

Tags: leaflet, drupal-8

I use Leaflet module in Drupal 8.
The map (based on Views) works fine.

I would like to change the default map tiles (OpenStreetMap) and use for instance one of the following maps : https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/.

Do somebody knows how can I manage that, please?

I have been looking for a while but not found the way to achieve that.

Thanks!

Emmanuel

Comment: Does this help? https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps

Comment: Thanks! Yes it helps. But I would need to use a map which is not in that leaflet_more_maps module list. I would like to use on of those: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Answer (score 1):

You can [create your own module](https://www.google.com/search?q=create%20your%20own%20module%20druapl%208&cad=h) and extend leaflet like so:

For example, create 2 files in a folder to add under modules/custom/leaflet_mymap:

- leaflet_mymap.info.yml
- leaflet_mymap.module

In the view, you can then select the "Custom Map" selection instead of OSM and it will show the following maps for example:

in the module file use the function:

```
function leaflet_mymap_leaflet_map_info() {
  return array(
    'Custom Maps' => array(
      'label' => 'Custom Map',
      'description' => t('Custom Map from Module'),
      'settings' => array(
        'dragging' => TRUE,
        'touchZoom' => TRUE,
        'scrollWheelZoom' => TRUE,
        'doubleClickZoom' => TRUE,
        'zoomControl' => TRUE,
        'attributionControl' => TRUE,
        'trackResize' => TRUE,
        'fadeAnimation' => TRUE,
        'zoomAnimation' => TRUE,
        'closePopupOnClick' => TRUE,
        'layerControl' => TRUE,
      ),


    'layers' => array(
        'Open Street Map' => array(
          'urlTemplate' => 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          'options' => array(
            'attribution' => '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
          ),
        ),
        'Open Topo Map' => array(
          'urlTemplate' => 'https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          'options' => array(
            'attribution' => '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
          ),
        ),
        'Hillshade' => array(
          'urlTemplate' => 'https://maps.heigit.org/openmapsurfer/tiles/asterh/webmercator/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          'layer_type' => 'overlay', //this gives you the ability to overlay transparent maps
          'options' => array(
            'attribution' => 'Imagery from <a href="http://giscience.uni-hd.de/">GIScience Research Group @ University of Heidelberg</a> | Map data  <a href="https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/aster_policies">ASTER GDEM</a>, <a href="http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/">SRTM</a>',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```